# config file ownership and permissions in linux

Tags: linux, config

What is the config file that lists all ownerships and permissions?

I know that most config files are stored in  the /etc directory. such as group and passwd.

So, my question is: If I created a file and the ownership was given to a specific user or group, where that info is stored?

Answer (score 0):

Every file has an **inode** entry in the filesystem what contains metadata information like permissions and ownership.

You can find more information:https://linoxide.com/linux-command/linux-inode/

Commands related to the ownership and permissions:

- list file permissions: `ls -l`
- change owner: `chown` command
- change permissions: `chmod` command